# Calculation of Total Required DC Link Bulk Capacitors in Motor Drive

Tags: current, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, bulk-capacitor

Would anyone let me know whether the following formula is correct to estimate the total amount of DC link bulk capacitors for a 3-phase permanent magnet motor drive to handle the startup inrush current and regenerative breaking current?

- C_bulk = (I_max * T)/dt

where,

- C_bulk = Total amount of DC link bulk capacitance in uF
- I_max =  Assumed maximum reverse current during regenerative breaking (200A)
- T =   Switching period of the FETs (1/fsw) (120KhZ)
- dt = maximum allowable ripple voltage (3V)

C_bulk = 555.28 uF (with the given data)

Is it correct? Should I add more around like 700 uF to Dc link?

I went through several research papers and they seem to use motor breaking current for the calculation.

I would much appreciate it if you would give me a direction or point me to any research paper considering the startup inrush current, normal phase current, and regenerative breaking current.

Comment: More capacitance = more inrush current (unrelated to the motor). Think about what I'm saying because this may end up being problematic. Can we have some numbers please?

Comment: say maximum phase current is 200 A, switching frequency varies from 40Khz or 100 Khz. Voltage ripple is 3V from the battery.

Comment: I am using fets to limit inrush current.

My inrush current is in KA range for 2 micro-sec in simulation which is down to 0A when I use the T_tao = RC principle for the capacitance charging circuit (Charge the DC link capacitance at 0.95*T_tao to limit the inrush current and charge with the battery voltage). I am using Rds_on (3mOhm) of FET as R here. But I can not figure out the FET turn-on time from Tao as less than 30ms cause a frequent charging cycle of the capacitors and cause a current spike of inrush current when the capacitor charges.

Comment: I also need help to understand the relationship between the inrush current and the amount of capacitance.

Comment: Add all relevant information into your question please.

Comment: Now, I added the numbers in the original question. 

Please also explain the relationship between the inrush current and the amount of capacitance.

Comment: [Capacitor inrush current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80365/capacitor-inrush-current)